# How to get static routing after a dynamic routing in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, routes, next.js

How to get for example `/users/[id]/activity` to change the status of the current user?

I tried `http://localhost:3000/api/users/1/activity` but was a 404 page, how to get the write path and to acquire the id from the previous folder ([id].js]
Path of the API:

```
users
 |   
 --[id].js (Folder)
    |
   activity (Folder)
    |
    index.js
```

users/[id].js/acitivity/index.js File:

```
import { getSession } from "next-auth/react";
export default async (req, res) => {
  const {
    query: { id },
    method,
  } = req;

  switch (method) {
    case "GET":
      return res.status(200).json({
        TEST: id,
      });

}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
users
 |   
 --[id]    (Remove  ".js")
    |
   activity (Folder)
    |
    index.js
```